# How to use aggregate map and filter for multiple arrays in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregate, aggregate-functions

Here i have Two arrays,

```
 Usercar = [{
            parentId :001
            cars:[
                   {_id: 1, name: bmw, color: red},
                   {_id: 2, name: Ford, color: black},
                   {_id: 3, name: Volkswagen, color: black},
                 ]
              }]


 Userfavorite = 
               [{
                  parentId :001,
                  favoriteCars:[1,3] //mongoose.Types.ObjectId
               }]
```

I want o show user favorite cars using mongodb aggregate, here is my code

```
let carsId= [1,3];


    {$match: {
        parentId :001
    }},
    {
        $project:{
            cars:{
                $filter:{

                        input:"$cars",
                        as :'cars',
                        cond:{ $eq :["$$cars._id", mongoose.Types.ObjectId('1')]}
                      //cond:{ $eq :["$$cars._id", carsId]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the above code only work, when pass single carsId, I want user favorite Cars details from Usercar's collection, how to do that in mongodb aggregate ?

Comment: @neil-lunn please take a look

Comment: Are `Usercar` and `Userfavorite` in the same document, or separate collections?

Comment: Its  separate collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible aggregate that could do this is:

- aggregate on the Usercar collection
- lookup the matching document from the Userfavorite collection
- in case there are multiple favorite documents, combine them into a single favorite array
- reduce the cars collection to find those matching the favorites, and add to an array

```
db.Usercar.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Userfavorite",
      localField: "parentId",
      foreignField: "parentId",
      as: "favorite"
  }},
  {$set: {
      favorite: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {$concatArrays: "$favorite.favoriteCars"},
          0
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      favoriteCarDetails: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cars",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this._id",
              "$favorite"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/50kgWoJsfvF)

Comment: `favoriteCarDetails` is empty :(

Comment: why we need concatArrays in the case ?

Comment: You don't necessarily, that just deals with the possibility that there are 2 matching documents in the other collection.  If there will only ever be one, you can just project it or unwind it to pull it out of the looked up array